# Errors when defining nft rules in multple places

Tags: nftables

My nftable file was growing too big. I tried to split it into smaller files and use `include`, but I got errors. I probably do not understand how are multiple parts merged together.

> nftables will read in all of the included config files, create the
> config object in memory alongside the existing config, and then in one
> atomic operation it swaps the old config for the new one

Here is a small nft file that works (i.e. can be loaded successfully)

```
# OK
table inet filter {
    set deny_ipv4_ipset {
        type ipv4_addr
        flags interval
    }   

    chain geoip {
        type filter hook prerouting priority mangle
        policy accept
        meta iiftype loopback accept
        ct state {related, established} accept
        ip saddr @deny_ipv4_ipset drop
    }   
}
```

But when I split it into two files, it cannot be loaded. It does not work even
if I keep it in one file and split it only "logically".

```
# not OK
table inet filter {
    set deny_ipv4_ipset {
        type ipv4_addr
        flags interval
    }
}

table inet filter {
    chain geoip {
        type filter hook prerouting priority mangle
        policy accept
        meta iiftype loopback  accept
        ct state {related, established}  accept
        ip saddr @deny_ipv4_ipset  drop
    }
}
```

The second file produces this error:

```
Error: No such file or directory; did you mean set ‘deny_ipv4_ipset’ in table inet ‘filter’?
ip saddr @deny_ipv4_ipset  drop
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Yes, I did mean the ‘deny_ipv4_ipset’ in table inet ‘filter’, so why this error occurred?

Comment: I guess it's related to the atomicity of ruleset loading. If you loaded the first file only, then separately (and without flushing anything) the 2nd file it would work

Comment: As you say, it is not because of the multiple files. I think it is because you define the same table twice. If I remember correctly there is something like functions that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, it is not because of the multiple files. I think it is because you define the same table twice. If I remember correctly there is something like functions that you can use.

The manual has an example of using include https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Classic_perimetral_firewall_example

```
table inet filter {
        …

        include "./inet-filter-sets.nft"
        include "./inet-filter-preroute-chains.nft"
}
```

`inet-filter-sets.nft`

```
set deny_ipv4_ipset {
    type ipv4_addr
    flags interval
}
```

Comment: It is not true that you cannot define the same table twice. It is not that simple, unfortunately. The example I gave in my question as not working will be accepted if you remove the line `ip saddr @deny_ipv4_ipset  drop`. It looks like `nft` cannot process the reference to `deny_ipv4_ipset`, because that name is not defined "locally". I miss a clear documentation in this regard.

Comment: I wonder if including the file with the definition will put it in scope. (I was originally assuming that it is a lexical include. But may be it is doing scoping)

Comment: I don't know. For instance it is possible to define a set in one file (static config) and add elements to the set in another file (dynamically created by a script). In that case the reference to the set defined works. And IMHO that is quite common usage pattern. I finished my setup by trial and error.